# Trouble in sending the mail to multiple recipients at the same time from outlook vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

here I am trying to send out a mail to multiple recipients from outlook vba.

the recipient mail address is taken from column A of  excel sheet. Whne I run the below code the error "Run Time error 1004; Method 'cells of object'_Global' failed"

how to send the same mail to multiple recipients at the same time.

> To:Abc@gmail.Com; bhy@gmail.com; rft@gmail.com CC:hjuy@gmail.com;
>   ijk@gmail.com Subject: test mail

```
Code:

Sub Sendmail()
     Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim iRow As Long

        iRow = 1

    sPath = "XX"
'   // Excel
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'   // Workbook
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath)
'   // Sheet
    Set xlSht = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1")


Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1))

      Recip = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
     ' subject = Cells(iRow, 2).Value
     ' Atmt = Cells(iRow, 3).Value '

'   // Create e-mail Item
    Set olItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olItem
    Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add(Recip)




        .CC = xlSht.Range("B1")

        .subject = "test"
        .Display
       .Send
    End With


'   // Close
    xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
'   // Quit
    xlApp.Quit

    '// CleanUp


      iRow = iRow + 1

   Loop
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlSht = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: Which offic/window  are you running?

Comment: Windows 8.1 desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should od the job for you.

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm